# Same formalism defining triangle type in terms of angles

Tags: geometry, definition, triangles

What same formalism can be used to define triangle type in terms of it's angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ ?
I can think just one :

**Right triangle**
$$ \{\alpha,\beta+\gamma \} \ni k = \pi/2 $$

Bonus points - from this we can deduce, that :
$$ \quad\sum_{k\in \{\alpha,\beta+\gamma \}}^n k = \alpha+\beta+\gamma = n \frac{\pi}{2} =  \pi $$

**Acute triangle**

$$ \{\alpha,\beta, \gamma \} \ni k < \pi/2 $$

**Obtuse triangle**

$$ \{\alpha,\pi- \left(\beta+\gamma\right) \} \ni k > \pi/2 $$

Any other uniform ways to describe triangle type in terms of it's angles ?

Comment: Your question confuses me. What is $k$? How can a _set_ of angles be compared to $\pi/2$? You can distinguish these types of triangles by comparing the _maximum_ angle to $\pi/2$.

Comment: i'm comparing not whole set, but element $k$ from an angle set. Should comparison operation be after $k$ variable instead ?

Comment: All this does is wrap a straightforward look at the largest angle with an expression using symbols that does not make mathematical sense. Perhaps we can help if you [edit] the question to tell us _why_ you need such an expression. (Don't respond in a comment.)

Comment: Just researching ways to represent triangle. If it doesn't makes much sense, then please fix it, posting your answer how to fix that. You are highly welcome. I understand your point that just max angle can be used instead. However max angle way skips relations between all three angles. I just wanted a way to involve all three angles somehow.

Comment: Btw, you can post your answer defining it through _max_ angle too. Would be interesting to see your solution, ANY. I need any answers

Comment: @EthanBolker, My definition not only wraps a straightforward look at the largest angle. From the right triangle definition one can deduce that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi$. Simple _max()_ expression will not let you to infer such knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be the angles of the triangle. Then the triangle is (acute, right, obtuse) when $\max(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$ is ($<$, $=$, $>$) $\pi/2$.